# IOS10＋IIS＋HTTPS＋自己証明書（オレオレ証明書）での位置情報取得について

Tags: ios10

私は以下の環境で開発しています。
OS：IOS10IIS
通信：HTTPS

さらに、自己証明書（オレオレ証明書）で開発中のWebアプリに接続しています。

しかし、位置情報を取得しようとすると、エラーが発生します。
「Geolocation error: Origin does not have permission to use Geolocation service.」

皆さんはどうやってこの問題を解決していますか？

Answer (score 2):

英語版のStackOverflowの以下の話題で取り上げられています。

[Got an error when trying to get the geolocation in safari on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633313/got-an-error-when-trying-to-get-the-geolocation-in-safari-on-ios-10)

HTTPSでアクセスしたページでも、その中に一つでもHTTPでアクセスしたコンテンツ（例えば、画像）が混ざっているとダメらしい。
httpでアクセスしているところを片っ端からhttpsに書き換えるのが対策のようです。